# Using ngStyle on the body tag on the main index.html in angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I couldn't find a way to use ngStyle on the index.html in the body tag using angular 2.

like on index.html:

```
  <body ngStyle="bodyStyle">
    Demo text
  </body>
```

The only way I found is using `"encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None"` in the component, however, only works using standard css class but not using a variable or function as ngStyle,

Like, on the component styles:

```
body {
      background: red;
   }
```

I also found something similar on angularjs as the link below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7cwAeGMsCYA8HIrWbl7d?p=preview

Is possible to have the same result in angular 2 as the link above ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that. `ngStyle` only works in the template of an Angular component. `<body>` can't be inside a components template.

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style instead.

Another way would be to use `'body'` as selector of your `AppComponent` and apply styles using `@HostBinding()`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.background-color') 
  backgroundColor:string = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a solution to almost all world problems :)

Comment: Sadly only "almost" :D

Comment: @micronyks lots of good answers from you as well and you joined about the same time AFAIR. Often I think my answer was just seconds before yours because I have faster internet ;-)

Comment: But it still takes a lot of effort continuing something this "good". Not the right place but you are a true champion @GünterZöchbauer ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't do much without questions though :D

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes I actually started after you. But due to some personal work n all, can't contribute to SO so much nowadays. Learnt many things from your answers. That's why you are a leader in Angular2 community in SO.  And for Internet don't know exactly but I guess that's probably true ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I did some test and this method only works on the "AppComponent.ts" but not from another component, in other to make it works let's said in "test.component.ts" I need to bootstrapped on "app.module" and by doing that I miss all the content from "AppComponent.ts"

Comment: I understand. You can always use plain JS/TS. I'm sure there is no other way provided by Angular. You could use the `Renderer’ if you wan't prevent direct DOM access.

Comment: I don't understand why is possible in angularjs but not in angular2